# Jenkins - MSBuild for ASP.NET CI without local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

Background: I am doing a POC for CI using Jenkins and MSBuild. I have installed Jenkins, MSBuild plugin and other required components on my machine and configured as well. But I don't have IIS configured on my development machine.

I want build the ASP.NET website and output the published code in a folder "c:\precompiledweb" using MSBuild script. I have

Can someone help me with MSBUild Script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the prerequisites for functionality.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt.aspx

Walkthrough: Deploying a Web Site Project by Using the Publish Web Site Tool

**Prerequisites**

*In order to complete this walkthrough, you will need the following:*

*Visual Studio.*

*This walkthrough assumes that you selected the Web Development collection of settings when you started Visual Studio the first time. For more information, see How to: Select Web Development Environment Settings.

**Access to Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) so that you can test the result of publishing a Web site project.** In this walkthrough, it is assumed that you have IIS running on your own computer. Alternatively, you can use any instance of IIS for which you have permission to create a virtual directory.*

You need access to some IIS server.

On the flip side....you need to keep this general rule in mind.  Jenkins is simply a fancy wrapper for command line calls.

So test the below (article) on your machine without IIS.  If you can get the command line to work (outside of jenkins), most likely you can get it working (inside jenkins)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure **Source Code Management** section, i.e. for TFS:

[image]

2. Add build step **"Execute Windows batch command"**

Insert msbuild invocation to your solution, i.e.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe 
"%WORKSPACE%\{solution_name}.sln"
```

You can add some [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

3. After build you can add another script invocation (batch, powershell, whatever) for copy project output to specific folder, but I would prefer another way: publish to IIS and run application immediately.

   - in Visual Studio create publish profile with WebDeploy target ([help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx))
   - enable Web Deploy in IIS on test machine ([help](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) - when componentes are already installed go to "USING THE IIS MANAGER TO CONFIGURE WEB DEPLOY FOR A NON-ADMINISTRATOR" section)
   - add publish parameters to jenkins job from step 2, i.e.:

     ```
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe 
     "%WORKSPACE%\ {solution_name}.sln" 
     /P:DeployOnBuild=true 
     /p:PublishProfile="{publish_profile_filename}.pubxml" 
     /p:Configuration=Release 
     /p:Platform="Any CPU" 
     /p:Password={Password_for_publish_profile_same_as_used_in_VS}
     ```

And now you have jenkins click-once job for build and publish solution to test server. Add Source Code change trigger and you have basic CI.